# -Rotating image

Tags: apache-flex, image, rotation

To image rotate I used Matrix class. Rotating work very well, but if I try scroll - image hide. How to solve this problem ? How to rotate big Image ?
Flex Code[Rotate]:

```
var tmpMatrix:Matrix = wImage.transform.matrix;
var oHeight:Number = wImage.height / 2;
var oWidth:Number = wImage.width / 2;``
tmpMatrix.translate(-oWidth, -oHeight);
tmpMatrix.rotate(-Math.PI / 2);
tmpMatrix.translate(oWidth, oHeight);
wImage.transform.matrix = tmpMatrix;
```

Best regards,
   mykhaylo

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, that code works depending on how is the image previously sized and positioned, and what you do after rotation.
What I do after rotating is modify matrix tx and ty in order to reposition the image, which is actually out of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the wImage.rotation property?